# How to copy and write file in the same directory using fs module in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

trying copy file from directory and writing new file in the same directory using `fs` module it seems not working not sure what has implemented wrong any help will be apprecaited , once new file is created then i will make changes in new json file is what i am trying to achieve .

main.js

```
     const fs = require("fs");
      async function copyAndCreateNewFile (path, files) {
     
            try {
                let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(files[0]);
                 let parsedJson = JSON.parse(rawdata);
                 console.log("JSON DATA", parsedJson);
                 let data = JSON.stringify(parsedJson);
                const newFile = fs.writeFileSync(`${path}/${"test.json"}`, data);
                return newFile;
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log ('not able to write data in the file ')
            }
        
      }

copyAndCreateNewFile('dir/services', ['dir/services/fileToCopy.json'])
```

Error

```
not able to write data in the file  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/test.json'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222992/discussion-on-question-by-hussain-how-to-copy-and-write-file-in-the-same-directo).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to copy a file in Node:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.copyFile('source', 'destination', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Make sure you have write permission to the destination dir.
For example:

```
sudo chmod 777 <destination-dir>
```

Comment: if OP code doesn't work, why would this? asking, not criticising

Comment: @domenikk copying is not the issue , its writing to new file

Comment: @hussain did you try chmod 777 to destination dir, or running node with sudo?